# Adjusting navigation bar text - CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having this current problem and I'm a bit confused. I would appreciate some help.

My current navigation bar looks like this:

[image]

I would like it to be like this:

[image]

Here is the relevant CSS code:

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100% auto;
}
nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    ;
}
.first {
    display:inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
}
@font-face {
    font-family:"Steelfish Rg";
    src: url(../fonts/steelfish_rg.ttf) format('truetype');
}
nav a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-family: Steelfish Rg, Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 51px;
    height: 78px auto;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    border-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100% auto;
}
@font-face {
    font-family:"Clarendon Lt BT";
    src: url(../fonts/20924071.ttf) format('truetype');
}
nav small {
    font-family: Clarendon Lt BT;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
    color: #ababaa;
    text align: left;
    font-weight: 700;
}
nav .bottom {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom: -11px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 19px;
}
```

as well as a part of the html for the navigation:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <a href="/eng/" class="first current">
                <small> get </small>
                <span> home </span>
                <small class="bottom">dude</small>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/74Lcfdz2/)**

I would appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: I almost think this would be easier if you just used 3 header tags and styled them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear with the parent container looks like, but using floats and clearing gets you close. For example:

```
nav .first .bottom {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/74Lcfdz2/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Currently all your elements are inline elements. You have to make them block elements to break every word into a new line.

```
  .first small {
     display: block;
  }
```